# Sci-Kit Learn SGD Classifier problems predicting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, data-analysis

I may not be able to find the help I need here, but I am hoping the smart coders of the internet can help me. I am attempting to use Python's Sci-Kit learn SGDClassifier to classify physical events. These physical events create an image of a track (black and white) and I am trying to get a classifier to classify them. The images are approx 500 * 400 pixels (not quite sure) but for machine-learning purposes it gives me a 200640 dimensional vector. I have 20000 train events serialized in data packages of 200 events. Then I have an extra 2000 train events. Here is how I go about extracting and training.

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
>>> import dill
>>> import glob
>>> import numpy as np

>>> clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge')

>>>for file in glob.glob('./SerializedData/Batch1/*.pkl'):
...    with open(file, 'rb') as stream:
...    minibatch = dill.load(stream)
...        clf.partial_fit(minibatch.data, minibatch.target, classes=np.classes([1, 2]))
(Some output stuff about the classifier)
>>>
```

This is the train part of my code, or at least a rough abbreviation of it. I do have a little bit more complicated initialization of the classifier. Just for more info the `minibatch.data` gives a numpy array of shapes and features so that is a "2-dimensional numpy array" with the shape being 200 and the features being 200640. To clear that up there are arrays describing the pixel values of each image and then 200 of them contained in a big array. `minibatch.target` gives a numpy array of all the class values of each event

However, after this training of 20000 events I try to test the classifier and it just does not seem to have been trained at all:

```
>>> file = open('./SerializedData/Batch2/train1.pkl', 'rb')
>>> test = dill.load(file)
>>> clf.predict(test.data)
array([ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2])
>>> clf.score(test.data)
.484999999999999999999
```

As you can see the classifier is predicting class 2 for all the test events. The only problem I can think of at the moment is that I do not have enough test events but I find that hard to believe. Does anybody have any suggestions/solutions/answers to this predicament?

Comment: Is your dataset balanced? Also remember that you are trying to use **linear** estimator now. Maybe it's possible to use some non-linear? SVM or some Ensemble method? If you don't have enough memory - maybe it's possible to compress data with PCA, or some another feature selection/extraction method?

Comment: i have enough memory because I open the serialized packages one by one. I only use the linear estimator here because the LinearSVM classifier performed at 60 percent accuracy when only trained on 1200 events however I need a method in which I could afford to train more than 1200 events  and thus decided to use SGD with hinge loss function. Essentially I need to use the partial_fit method.

Comment: Could just be bad parameters for the classifier. How do you instantiate your classifier object? Have you tried a random grid search CV?

Comment: Recovering the question from @Olologin, it might be that your dataset *is not balanced*, i.e. you have 80% of training instances belonging to class 2 while only 20% to class 1. If this happens the classifier will be biased towards class 2 (making predictions of class 2 more probable). Have a look to the `class_weight` parameter, by default all classes have weight `1`. I would suggest trying with `class_weight='auto'` as it will assign class weights inversely proportional to the class frequencies in the training set.

Comment: training set is balanced, however I will attempt your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Unless your images are exceptionally simple, you aren't going to get good results using just scikit learn if your inputs are images. You need to transform the images in some way to obtain actually useful features, pixel values make terrible features. You could try using some of the tools in [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) to create better features, or you could use some of the pre-trained convolutional neural networks to extract features for you. If you were feeling more adventurous, you could try and train a CNN to do the classification for your problem in particular.